# Is there a way to add an endpoint on magento without creating a new module?

Tags: magento-community, stock, page

I'm trying to add in a single file on the root folder
something than given a sku or id (it can be either get or post)

it will return me the stock as plain text.

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to do something like.

```
$products=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
foreach($products as $_product){
$stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);
echo $stock->getQty();
echo $stock->getMinQty();
echo $stock->getMinSaleQty();
}
```

but this file isn't connected to Magento

sorry for the bad english,

Comment: Are you looking something for like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29941585/magento-including-php-file-in-the-root-folder)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the index.php, and instead of calling `Mage::run()`, call:

```
Mage::app('admin', 'store');
```

Then after the call above, you can run your Magento code with full access

**BIG WARNING NOTE:** This grants unauthenticated access to whatever your script does.

Comment: thanks, I know it-s not the best aproach, but we need an endpoint to be accesed by anyone to show stock based on sku

Answer (score 1):

This is the proper way to call the magento functionality in your custom file on root of magento. 
You have to call these first 2 line in your code and rest coding as per magento standards.

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$products=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
foreach($products as $_product){
    $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);
    echo $stock->getQty();
    echo $stock->getMinQty();
    echo $stock->getMinSaleQty();
}
?>
```